# Centos8 - After a login systemd touches /boot/grub2

Tags: centos, systemd

I'm using Centos8 on a mini-PC as a router/firewall, and run Tripwire.  I'm the only one who ever logs in, always as a non-privileged user, not root (ssh root login is disabled).

Every time I login, the `/boot/grub2` directory's "Modify time" and "Change time" attributes get changed, which causes it to be flagged in Tripwire.

I think I've traced this to `systemd', which runs "Mark boot as successful" 2 minutes after a user logs in. The relevant line in the system log is:

```
Mar 31 15:49:46 janus systemd[5911]: Started Mark boot as successful after the user session has run 2 minutes.
```

First of all, deciding the boot was successful based on a user logging in seems like an awful kludge... what if it's a remotely attended system and nobody logs in?  (rhetorical question).

My real question is can I just disable this `systemd` unit, or will that cause other things to not work as expected?

### Additional Information

I've traced this to the `systemctl` service `/lib/systemd/user/grub-boot-success.service`, which contains:

```
[jhg@janus ~]$ more /lib/systemd/user/grub-boot-success.service
[Unit]
Description=Mark boot as successful

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/grub2-set-bootflag boot_success
```

This is being run 2 minutes after every user login instead of once per boot after the *first* user login, and this is what is touching the file and directory.

Is this working as intended, or should I file a bug report?

Will disabling this hurt anything?

Comment: How come you traced this to systemd, rather than to [GRUB2](https://github.com/rhboot/grub2/blob/fedora-29/docs/grub-boot-success.service)?

Comment: Is it really "2 minutes after a user logs in" rather than "after all system services have completed starting up"? `systemd` enables logins as soon as possible, and other system daemons may still be in the process of starting up if you log in immediately after a reboot. Anyway, use `rpm -qf /lib/systemd/system/grub-boot-success.service` to determine which package provides that service file - it does not seem to exist on my RHEL 8 test VM that uses a minimal configuration, so it is probably an optional package.

Comment: @telcoM Yes, 2 minutes after every user login the service is run, touching the directory.